# C# reference collection for storing reference types

Tags: c#, collections, pass-by-reference

I like to implement a collection (something like `List<T>`) which would hold **all** my objects that I have created in the entire life span of my application as if its an array of pointers in C++. The idea is that when my process starts I can use a central factory to create all objects and then periodically validate/invalidate their state. Basically I want to make sure that my process only deals with valid instances and I don't re-fetch information I already fetched from the database. So all my objects will basically be in one place - my collection. A cool thing I can do with this is avoid database calls to get data from the database if I already got it (even if I updated it after retrieval its still up-to-date if of course some other process didn't update it but that a different concern). I don't want to be calling `new Customer("James Thomas");` again if I initted James Thomas already sometime in the past. Currently I will end up with multiple copies of the same object across the appdomain - some out of sync other in sync and even though I deal with this using `timestamp` field on the MSSQL server I'd like to keep only one copy per customer in my appdomain (if possible process would be better).

I can't use regular collections like List or ArrayList for example because I cannot pass parameters by their real local reference to the their existing Add() methods where I'm creating  them using `ref` so that's not to good I think. So how can this be implemented/can it be implemented at all ? A 'linked list' type of class with all methods working with `ref` & `out` params is what I'm thinking now but it may get ugly pretty quickly. Is there another way to implement such collection like `RefList<T>.Add(ref T obj)`?

So bottom line is: I don't want re-create an object if I've already created it before during the entire application life unless I decide to re-create it explicitly (maybe its out-of-date or something so I have to fetch it again from the db). Is there alternatives maybe ?

Comment: Have you ever heard about Ioc Container?

Comment: What do you mean by "real local reference"? You are misunderstanding and misusing `ref` and `out`, IMO.

Comment: Adding the objects to the collection is actually storing references to the object.  I don't see what your problem with using a List<T> is.  Could you explain a little more.

Comment: @ivo: Correct.  It is storing a pointer(reference) to the object.  IE You create an object then store a pointer to that object into a variable.  Later, you copy that pointer into your List<t>.  You now have 2 identical pointers to that object.  What is the problem?

Comment: @ivo Sorry, my response was not supposed to be offensive.

Comment: @Ivo:Now I understand what you are trying to do.  What if you only retrieve pointers to the pointer held in the collection.  That way, when the pointer in the collection becomes null, it breaks.

Comment: @Ivo: I'm not certain, it is a little lower level then you would usually go in C#, but this page should help.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

Comment: @Ivo What is it you're trying to achieve by making the object null?  As Stefan says, this isn't something you'd generally have to try and do in C#, there could be a more .Net-y way of achieving it without resorting to pointers.

Comment: @Ivo: Haha, Yeah I just saw that.  The problem That I'm coming across is that no matter what you do, they will have a legitimate pointer to the object.  GC will not clear out that object, because there is still a pointer to it.  The other option would be to essentially notify your consumers of objects when the object gets an update, using a delegate or something like that.

Comment: continuation:  You could then use these events to tell your consuming classes to reaquire references to the objects that they need in your collection.

Comment: @Ivo: My suggestions should in no way imply that I think this is a good practice.  Frankly, if i find myself needing to keep all of my objects in one location, and update them around the application sporadically, I would seriously consider re-architecting myapplication.  That being said, this does provide and interesting thought puzzle.

Comment: @Ivo: It is awesome that it behaves like that.  Otherwise you would be doing manual memory management, which trust me, is no fun.  Sure, it does give you a little more control, but I much prefer .net handling it for me.

Comment: @Ivo: another option.  have a class that wraps your collection and essentially acts as a factory for your objects.  Every time a consuming class needs an object, it has to request it through the wrapping class.  This will keep the likelyhood of a consuming class having a bad reference to a minimum.

Comment: @ivo, to do a bit of root cause analysis, why can't there be multiple references to your object?  Will this cause a memory leak as some references will never be removed?  Are you marking the object as 'no longer valid' or whatever by making it null, so the other references don't try to use it?  Is it a concurrency issue?  Are you concerned about controlling where the object's stage gets modified? etc

Comment: @Ivo: Depending on if you have control over the objects (they are ones you have defined) you could have a property on them that means they are flagged for needing an update.  then when your consuming class sees that it is flagged, it gets a new reference.

Comment: @Ivo, I think I understand the problem, but isn't that caused by having multiple copies of the object, as opposed to multiple references to the same object?  If so, wouldn't some kind of cache which returned a reference to the existing object work Ok without using pointers?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do what you're trying to accomplish is to create a wrapper that holds on to the list. This wrapper will have an add method which takes in a ref. In the add it looks up the value in the list and creates it when it can't find the value. Or a Cache

But... this statement would make me worry.

> I don't want re-create an object if
>   I've already created it before during
>   the entire application life

But as Raymond Chen points out that [A cache with a bad policy is another name for a memory leak](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/02/588350.aspx). What you've described is a **cache with no policy**

To fix this you should consider using  for a non-web app either [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28VS.100%29.aspx) for 4.0 or for 3.5 and earlier the [Enterprise Library Caching Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx). If this is a Web App then you can use the [System.Web.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aspx). Or if you must roll your own at least get a sensible policy in place.

All of this of course assumes that your database's caching is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ioc will save you many many many bugs, and make your application easier to test and your modules will be less coupled. 
Ioc performance are pretty good.
I recommend you to use the implementation of Castle project 
http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx

maybe you'll need a day to learn it, but it's great.

Comment: IOC Containers can be useful, but I'm not entirely sure how they relate to this question

Comment: The guy wanna manage all existing instances in the system. what can be more related?