# How to pass string into collection by reference?

Tags: c#, collections, pass-by-reference

It seems that string is reference, but copied by value

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
string s = "a";
data.Add(s); // copy by value??
s = "b";
Console.WriteLine(data[0]); // "a"
```

It also seems that class is reference copied by reference

```
class boxstring { public string val; }
List<boxstring> data = new List<boxstring>();
boxstring s = new boxstring { val = "a" };
data.Add(s); // copy by reference, ok
s.val = "b";
Console.WriteLine(data[0].val); // "b"
```

**Is there a simpler way to pass string into collection by reference without wrapping it into class?** I'd like to pass object member into collection and if the object is changed, the collection should be also changed without writing extra code.

Comment: A string is no different than any other class. The important line is `s = "b";`. This is reassignment. Note that any class would exhibit this same behavior in the list. *Mutations* of the *instance* are observed. *Reassignments* of the *variable* are not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# reference collection for storing reference types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569062/c-sharp-reference-collection-for-storing-reference-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Whenever you assign new value to string variable, a new instance is created everytime that's why you can't see the updates in your collection.

However, .NET already provide mutable counterpart of string i.e. "`StringBuilder`". This will work for you -

```
List<StringBuilder> data = new List<StringBuilder>();
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("a");
data.Add(s);
s.Clear();
s.Insert(0, "b");
Console.WriteLine(data[0]); // "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, if you want the objects in your container to change, they must be mutable. Therefore, you must wrap them in a class like you did.

Comment: That's exactly what you did. You can play with some generics to make it a little nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea to make you code simpler :

```
public MyString
{
public string Value{get;set;}
public MyString(string value)
{
Value=value;
}



public static implicit operator MyString(string value)
{
return new MyString(value);
}

public static implicit operator string(MyString mystring)
{
if(mystring==null) return null;
return mystring.Value;
}
```

then you can use MyString object whenever you want to have string by reference.since we have these implicit operator in place you can use MyString instead of string

Comment: It seemed to be promising, but the implicit operator MyString creates a new instance, so the connection with the item in List is lost after reassigning new value.

Comment: you can store MyString in your list. And I forget that you didn't want an immutable string :) then there should be a way to change the value of MyString .I will edit the source :)

Comment: Well you are right MyString="new string" won't change the value of the same reference but it creates a new instance thus the previous instance will have its previous value.It seems that using operator overloading won't help us in this situation.

Comment: But it can be still used as `s.Value = "b";` once s is created. +1 from me.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot pass intrinsic data-types by reference, they are always passed by value.
Intrinsic types include basic types like Int32, String, Bool, etc..

Comment: And what about `ref` keyword? It enables to pass argument by reference, even intrinsic types.